# Managing repositories in synch after splitting master repository

Tags: git, repository

Hello Stack Community,
Recently we spitted our main/joined repository (containing frontend and backend implementatons):

```
.git
 +--backend
 +--frontend
```

Into two separate repositories:

```
.git
 +--backend
```

and

```
.git
 +--frontend
```

Unfortunately, before Ops team is up and running with deployment of new ones (splitted), some new requests falls in to be implemented and deployed, so they landed into joined repository. Now there is obvious issue with synchronization, because each change introduced in joined repo must be propagated into new spitted ones. For last two days I'm doing this tedious work by hand (copy-paste from common repo to frontend/backend, each located in separate directory), but I imagine that this situation occurs in our business common enough that some good practices were introduced to handle such temporary state?

Comment: I suppose that I'd add the joined repo as a remote `git remote add joinedOrigin https://github.com/<your_stuff>` then just merging/cherry-picking the commits to where you need it. Let me know if you need less conceptual instructions!

Comment: @FredrikS, to be honest I'd love to hear more, probably in answer form, not as a comment :)